# selecting only the available data on Many2one field

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo

I've created a module `asset.management.handover` and `asset.management.handover.lines` to save all the selected assets to it.

I am done on filtering the data on Many2one field like below.
Here is my .py code:

```
asset_name_id = fields.Many2one('account.asset.asset', string = "Asset", 
required = True)
serial_number_id = fields.Many2one('account.asset.asset.line', string = 
"Serial number", required = True)
```

my .xml code:

```
<field name="asset_name_id"/>
<field name="serial_number_id" domain = "[('serial_no_id', '=', 
asset_name_id)]"/>
```

If I select asset1, all the available serial no. to asset1 can be selected. The problem is:

I want to, if, for example, I select asset1 then select serial no. 123 then I want to select another item which is asset1 again then when I want to select serial no. again, there it goes to the problem, serial no. 123 is available again. All I want to achieve is, serial no. 123 will be no longer available to Many2one and cannot be seen to that field.

[please click this link to view the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DyGGW.png)

(edited)
This is my full code of .py

```
from odoo import api, fields, models
from datetime import datetime

class AssetManagementHandover (models.Model):
    _name = 'asset.management.handover'

    name = fields.Char(string = "Sequence")
    issuer_company_id = fields.Many2one ('res.partner', string = "Issuer's 
    Company")

    issuer_id = fields.Many2one ('hr.employee', string = "Issuer's Name")
    issuer_email = fields.Char (string = "Email", readonly = True, related = 
    'issuer_id.user_id.login', store = True)
    source_loc = fields.Many2one ('stock.warehouse', string = "Source 
    Location")

    recipient_company_id = fields.Many2one ('res.partner', string = 
    "Recipient's Company")
    recipient_id = fields.Many2one ('hr.employee', string = "Recipient's 
    Name")
    destination_loc = fields.Many2one ('stock.warehouse', string = 
    "Destination Location")

    remarks = fields.Text (string = "Remarks")

    date = fields.Date (string = "Date", default = lambda *a: 
    datetime.today())
    transfer_type = fields.Char (string = "Transfer type", default = "Asset 
    Handover", readonly = True)
    custodian_id = fields.Many2one ('res.users', string = "Custodian",     
    readonly = True, default=lambda self: self.env.uid)
    processed_by = fields.Many2one ('hr.employee', string = "Processed by", 
    readonly = True)
    lines_ids = fields.One2many('asset.management.handover.lines', 
    'lines_id', string = " ")

    state = fields.Selection ([
    ('draft', "Draft"),
    ('transfer', "Transferred"),
    ('cancel', "Cancelled"),
    ], string = "State", default = 'draft')

    @api.onchange('issuer_company_id')
    def onchange_company(self):
        self.issuer_id = ''
        self.emp_email = ''
        self.source_loc = ''

    @api.multi
    def button_transfer(self):
        self.state = 'transfer'
        self.processed_by = self.env['hr.employee'].browse(self.env.uid)

    @api.multi
    def button_cancel(self):
        self.state = 'cancel'
        self.processed_by = ''

class AssetManagementHandoverLine (models.Model):
_name = 'asset.management.handover.lines'

lines_id = fields.Many2one('asset.management.handover')
asset_name_id = fields.Many2one('account.asset.asset', string = "Asset", required = True)
serial_number_id = fields.Many2one('account.asset.asset.line', string = "Serial number", required = True)
model = fields.Char (string = "Model", related = 'asset_name_id.model_id', store = True, readonly = True)
condition_id = fields.Many2one ('asset.condition', string = "Asset Condition", required = True)
state = fields.Char (string = "State")
asset_pic = fields.Char(string = "Asset picture")
total = fields.Integer(string = "Total", default = "1")

@api.onchange('asset_name_id')
def on_change(self):
    self.serial_number_id = ''
```

this is my form view of asset.management.handover in xml

```
<!--Hand over form view-->
    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="handover_form_view">
        <field name="name">handover.form.view</field>
        <field name="model">asset.management.handover</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form>
                <header>
                    <button name="button_transfer" string="Transfer"     
type="object" state="cancel"/>
                    <button name="button_cancel" string="Cancel" 
type="object"/>
                    <field name="state" widget="statusbar"/>
                </header>
                <sheet>
                    <group>
                        <group>
                            <field name="date"/>
                            <field name="issuer_company_id" 
placeholder="Company name" domain="[('is_company','=',True)]"/>
                            <field name="issuer_id" placeholder="Employee's 
Name" domain = "[('address_id', '=', issuer_company_id)]"/>
                            <field name="source_loc" domain = "
[('partner_id', '=', issuer_company_id)]"/>
                            <field name="issuer_email"/>
                            <field name="remarks"/>
                        </group>
                        <group>
                            <field name="transfer_type"/>
                            <field name="recipient_company_id" 
placeholder="Company name" domain="[('is_company','=',True)]"/>
                            <field name="recipient_id" 
placeholder="Employee's Name" domain = "[('address_id', '=', 
recipient_company_id)]"/>
                            <field name="destination_loc" domain = "
[('partner_id', '=', recipient_company_id)]"/>
                            <field name="custodian_id"/>
                            <field name="processed_by"/>
                        </group>

                        <field name="lines_ids">
                            <tree editable="bottom">
                                <field name="asset_name_id"/>
                                <field name="serial_number_id" domain = "
[('serial_no_id', '=', asset_name_id)]"/>
                                <field name="model"/>
                                <field name="condition_id"/>
                                <field name="state"/>
                                <field name="asset_pic"/>
                                <field name="total" sum="total" string = 
"Total Asset"/>
                            </tree>

                            <form>
                                <sheet>
                                    <group>
                                        <group>
                                           <field name="asset_name_id"/>
                                            <field name="serial_number_id" 
domain = "[('serial_no_id', '=', asset_name_id)]"/>
                                            <field name="model"/>
                                            <field name="condition_id"/>
                                        </group>
                                        <group>
                                            <field name="state"/>
                                            <field name="asset_pic"/>
                                        </group>
                                    </group>
                                </sheet>
                            </form>
                        </field>
                    </group>
                </sheet>
            </form>
        </field>
    </record>
```

Comment: You would need to keep track of all used serial numbers on the parent model (e.g. `asset.management.handover`), then you could use the domain to exclude all serial numbers that are present in that list. If you can provide the full code for both your `handover` and `handover.line` model I may be able to help more :)

Comment: done edited sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way to do this is to have the values checked on the `write` or `create` methods. And if a serial exists on more than 1 products raise an exception.

Another way would be to set a dynamic domain. You can say for example the following:

When `field1` changes, I want to be able to select only from these records on `field2`

So, define an `onchange` and return

`return {'domain': {'field_id': [('id', 'not in', used_serials)]}}`

Where on `used_serials` you will have the ids of the serials you already used.

Comment: @api.onchange('serial_number_id')
    def onchange_serial(self):
        res = {}
        if self.serial_number_id:
            res['domain'] = {'account.asset.asset.line': [('id', 'in', self.serial_number_id.id)]}
        print res
        return res

is my syntax correct? i already get the id that already taken. what would i do next?